# ASP.NET Core 2.2 Correlation error using AzureAD authentication in Kubernetes

Tags: azure-active-directory, aspnetcore-environment

We are deploying an ASP.NET Core 2.2 web app using Azure AD authentication and its working properly in local environment. But when deployed to Azure Kubernetes using Github Actions, we encountered the following error 'Correlation failed':

[image]

This is what we also captured in Kiali console after authenticating to Azure AD

[image]

See below our `Startup.cs` snippet

[image]